# Make CasperJS fully reload fragment (hashbang) links

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, hashbang

When I use the example [here](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/samples/dynamic.js) I find that a range of hashbang links on the same page (that dynamically creates different content) only generates the content the first time. For all the other results, the `this.getHTML()` from the first link is used.

E.g. when I load `http://test.localhost/` and it finds:

```
http://test.localhost/#!/page1
http://test.localhost/#!/page2
http://test.localhost/#!/page3
```

Every iteration uses the content of `#!/page1`. When I add the list in reverse order, every iteration uses the content of `#!/page3`. It's like everything works perfectly the first time, but CasperJS or PhantomJS internally detects a hash change in stead of a new URL, doesn't load the `onHashChange` functionality, and ignores it.

How do I make CasperJS load every URL anew, even only if the hash changes, as if it was opened the first time?

I'm using PhantomJS 1.9.18 that comes automatically with the [Grunt job](https://github.com/ronaldlokers/grunt-casperjs).

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you use? Have you tried PhantomJS 2 (may need to install CasperJS from git)?

Comment: `1.9.18`, comes automatically with the [`Grunt` job](https://github.com/ronaldlokers/grunt-casperjs). I do not wish to change what upstream gives me. So if you're saying this is a problem with an older version, I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug in PhantomJS 1.x (no guarantees). If you don't want to update PhantomJS to version 2, you might want to do each iteration with "a clean slate" judging by your observations. It seems that you're opening the pages sequentially like this:

```js
casper.thenOpen(url[0], function(){ /* do something*/ });
casper.thenOpen(url[1], function(){ /* do something*/ });
casper.thenOpen(url[2], function(){ /* do something*/ });
```

One way to workaround this issue might be to load a completely different page in between those invocations:

```js
casper.thenOpen(url[0], function(){ /* do something*/ });
casper.thenOpen("http://example.com");
casper.thenOpen(url[1], function(){ /* do something*/ });
casper.thenOpen("http://example.com");
casper.thenOpen(url[2], function(){ /* do something*/ });
```

http://example.com is perfect for cases like this, because it's always online and very small, but this still produces unnecessary requests. Another way would be to reset the current page to "about:blank" after you're done with it:

```js
casper.thenOpen(url[0], function(){ /* do something*/ });
casper.then(function(){ this.page.content = ""; });
casper.thenOpen(url[1], function(){ /* do something*/ });
casper.then(function(){ this.page.content = ""; });
casper.thenOpen(url[2], function(){ /* do something*/ });
```

[`page.content = ''`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html) empties the content of the page and also changes the current URL, so that the next open operation can be clean.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. Waiting to see what my final solution will be.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation very similar with PhantomJS. It was driving me absolutely insane. It took forever to figure out but my "little" hack around was:

```
return client
  .url('about:blank') // Weee
  .url('http://www.foo.com/#meow')
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
```